# Passing value of html tag to HTMLHelper

Tags: razor

I have a HTMLHelper:

```
public static string ResultsFor(string input)
    {

        return string.Format(ResourceManager.GetString("ResultsFor", resourceCulture), input);

    }
```

I need to call this method from `cshtml` file passing value of selected `html` tag, something like:

```
@Resources.Home.ResultsFor($("#search-input-mobile").value))
```

which does not work :-(

What is the proper approach here?

Thank you!

Comment: That's not possible as it looks like you're trying to use client side javascript via (I assume) jQuery, into a server side method.

Comment: you will need to post up more of your form html and code if anyone is going to be able to help

Comment: So how can I merge value taken from resources with data entered by user? 

For example: 

user entered 'John Walker', translated resources are: 'User entered: ' and as result I want to see: 'User entered: John Walker'\

Comment: As I said. Post up some more of your code and then SO can help you